# Selenium AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_css_selector'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am following [this](https://maoviola.medium.com/a-complete-guide-to-web-scraping-linkedin-job-postings-ad290fcaa97f) build of a scraper for LinkedIn job data.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search?keywords=&location=San%20Francisco%2C%20California%2C%20United%20States&locationId=&geoId=102277331&f_TPR=&distance=100&position=1&pageNum=0'

wd = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'/Users/voi/chromedriver')
wd.get(url)

no_of_jobs = int(wd.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('h1>span').get_attribute('innerText'))
```

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50755766/selenium-attributeerror-object-has-no-attribute-find-element-by-css-selector), and attempted the solution, but received a similar error, except with regards to the WebDriver object not having a driver attribute.

Here is the full error message:

```
cd /Users/voi ; /usr/bin/env /usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/voi/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2
022.8.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/launcher 59402 -- /Users/voi/jobscrape.py 
/Users/voi/jobscrape.py:7: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  wd = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'/Users/voi/chromedriver')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/voi/jobscrape.py", line 10, in <module>
    no_of_jobs = int(wd.find_element_by_css_selector('h1>span').get_attribute('innerText'))
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_css_selector'
```

Answer (score 34):

Okay, I answered my own question. The individual methods find_element_by_* have been replaced by find_element, e.g.

```
no_of_jobs = int(wd.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'h1>span'))
```

More info is [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

Comment: You are also getting the `DeprecationWarning` to resolve this you can see this [https://stackoverflow.com/a/72275260/11863448] , hope this will help you.

Answer (score 31):

Selenium recently [removed](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/10712) the 16 deprecated `find_element(s)_by_x` functions in favor of a general `find_element` and `find_elements` function that take the "by" part as their first argument.

To update your code, you can use your IDE's find-and-replace-all feature to replace these 16 search terms:

```
.find_element_by_class_name(
.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 

.find_element_by_css_selector(
.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 

.find_element_by_id(
.find_element(By.ID, 

.find_element_by_link_text(
.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, 

.find_element_by_name(
.find_element(By.NAME, 

.find_element_by_partial_link_text(
.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, 

.find_element_by_tag_name(
.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 

.find_element_by_xpath(
.find_element(By.XPATH, 

.find_elements_by_class_name(
.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 

.find_elements_by_css_selector(
.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 

.find_elements_by_id(
.find_elements(By.ID, 

.find_elements_by_link_text(
.find_elements(By.LINK_TEXT, 

.find_elements_by_name(
.find_elements(By.NAME, 

.find_elements_by_partial_link_text(
.find_elements(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, 

.find_elements_by_tag_name(
.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 

.find_elements_by_xpath(
.find_elements(By.XPATH,
```

You'll also need to import `By` if you haven't already done so:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Answer (score 5):

Selenium just removed that method in version `4.3.0`. See the CHANGES: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/a4995e2c096239b42c373f26498a6c9bb4f2b3e7/py/CHANGES

```
Selenium 4.3.0
* Deprecated find_element_by_* and find_elements_by_* are now removed (#10712)
* Deprecated Opera support has been removed (#10630)
* Fully upgraded from python 2x to 3.7 syntax and features (#10647)
* Added a devtools version fallback mechanism to look for an older version when mismatch occurs (#10749)
* Better support for co-operative multi inheritance by utilising super() throughout
* Improved type hints throughout
```

You now need to use:

```py
driver.find_element("css selector", SELECTOR)
```

In your example, you would use:

```py
no_of_jobs = int(wd.find_element("css selector", "h1 > span").get_attribute("innerText"))
```

For improved reliability, you should consider using `WebDriverWait` in combination with `visibility_of_element_located`.

Here's how that might look:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

# ...

element = WebDriverWait(wd, 10).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located(("css selector", "h1 > span"))
)
no_of_jobs = int(element.get_attribute("innerText"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Selenium version 4.0, the methods `find_element_by_*` and `find_elements_by_*` are no longer recommended to be used and have been replaced by the methods `find_element(`) and `find_elements()`.

These new methods allow you to locate elements on a web page by specifying a search strategy, such as by CSS selector, ID, name, etc.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search?keywords=&location=San%20Francisco%2C%20California%2C%20United%20States&locationId=&geoId=102277331&f_TPR=&distance=100&position=1&pageNum=0'

wd = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'/Users/voi/chromedriver')
wd.get(url)
element = WebDriverWait(wd, 20).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h1>span"))
)
```

Please checkout details [here](https://www.nbshare.io/notebook/609445379/How-To-Use-Selenium-Webdriver-To-Crawl-Websites/)

Answer (score 0):

To add on to the answer from @m.lekk ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/72854301/7733418 ), I also tried to use `dir()` to get all the attributes from the object and find the `text` attribute that contains the information that I need.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33240160)